# chart date interval (X: date, Y: text label) with c3.js

Tags: c3.js

I would want to make a c3.js chart with :

- X: date
- Y: text label ("TOTO", "TITI", "TUTU", ... : ok with "category" property, it's possible)
- line corresponding to interval date : (eg, april-15 until june-01)

[image: chart wished]

How can i make that ? Impossible in c3.js but possible in d3.js ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible using C3js, you can just use Bar chart in combination with rotated axis
https://c3js.org/samples/axes_rotated.html. Only catch will be data series which you pass.

Comment: Hello,

however, with this example, how do you make interval date ?

Comment: You can use timeseries in y axis https://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html and category in x-axis

Comment: Thanks.
This is not the same thing.
In your example, one value for a date.
In my example, this is an interval ! 01-April until 05-june for the first element in Y, 10-January until 03-March for the 2nd element in Y.

Comment: You re still not getting the context what I explained you. Imagine you have category on x axis and continuous time series range in y axis just like grouped bar chart in c3js. Now you just need to rotate the axis and that should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @NishantPatel.
i'm going to make that, and i will copy picture of my graphics, and we can talk again about that.

Comment: Hello @NishantPatel,
i tried to make a code simple, with x axis, category, y : timeseries range.
i put the code here : https://www.codepile.net/pile/WbeE15bE


I didn"t get that i want. y axis is not correct.
I'm ok with your suggestions however I don't know how realize that concretely.

Do you see every problems in my code ?
Thx in advance.